# Submit current URL to page that will later redirect to that same URL

Tags: php, url, redirect, submit

I have a form that submits with hidden inputs so an item can be added to the cart.

In order to avoid resubmission issues (if user refreshes the page or presses back from another page) I am doing it as follows:

- Item page has the form and submits
- cartAdding.php receives the values and adds the item to the cart. Then I put a `header` to redirect back to the item page

```php
include ("../cart/functions.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_POST['add']=='add' && $_POST['itemId']>0)
{
    if (array_key_exists($pid, $_SESSION['cart']['itemId']))
    { 
    }
    else 
    {
        $pid=$_REQUEST['itemId'];
        addtocart($pid,1);
        $itemAdded = 1;
        $max = 0; 
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) 
    { 
        $max = $max + $item['qty']; 
    }
    }
unset($_POST['add']);
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit();
}
```

My question is about the `Location`. How can I store the item's url so I can use it in cartAdding.php for the redirection? Is it a good practice to submit it with the form, calling it like this: `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another hidden input with its URL..

But isn't the item's URL derived from its id? Like `itemList.php?id=item_id`? If so, you already have its id (on `$pid = $_REQUEST['itemId'];`), so you can redirect to that, with

```php
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/itemList.php?id='.$pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass this URL or ItemId or whatever by $_POST or $_GET or even $_SESSION variable.